# Trying to convert a .txt. to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following in a text file:
(Altered the code to have fictional names and phonenumbers)

```
Harry Law +310011223344
Ben Biggy +310022334456
John Smit +312233445566
```

I would like to add this to a Dictionary in Python. This is the code that I currently have:

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as document:
    answer = {}
    for line in document:
        line = line.split("+")
        if not line:
            continue
        answer[line[0]] = line[1:]
print(answer)
```

This is my output:

```
{'Harry Law ': ['310011223344\n'], 'Ben Biggy ': ['310022334456\n'], 'John Smit ': ['312233445566']}
```

Now as you can see, it somewhat works. However, there are brackets around the phonenumbers, the "+" sign isn't there, and there is a '\n' at the end of each line.

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As for the brackets, they mean a list.
The dictionary values are lists because you use `[1:]`, which is list slicing and not item accessing. Use `[1]` instead.

And to remove the newlines (`\n`), use `.strip()` on the extracted lines.

After all, it should look like this:

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as document:
    answer = {}
    for line in document:
        line = line.split("+")
        if not line:
            continue
        answer[line[0]] = line[1].strip()
    print(answer)
```

Besides, I'd refactor this to:

```
    with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as document:
    answer = {}
    for line in document:
        if line:
            line = line.split("+")
            answer[line[0]] = line[1].strip()
    print(answer)
```

I think it's more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Nuances in your code:

- *"the "+" sign isn't there"* - with this line `line = line.split("+")` you have split the text line by `+` loosing the sepatator
- *"and there is a '\n' at the end of each line"* - because you are iterating over a [**file object**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)  with this feature:

> In text mode, the default when reading is to convert platform-specific
>   line endings (`\n` on Unix, `\r\n` on Windows) to just `\n`

The shortest one:

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = { l[:l.index('+')].strip() : l[l.index('+'):].strip() 
               for l in f.read().splitlines() }

print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'John Smit': '+312233445566', 'Ben Biggy': '+310022334456', 'Harry Law': '+310011223344'}
```

Comment: Thank you! Great explaination